# Cannot create a subfolder or subpackage in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aibtn.png)

The packages appear like this:

```
-crom.bezkoder.spring.datajpa
-crom.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.controller
-crom.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.model
-crom.bezkoder.spring.datajpa.repository
```

Instead of (like in the picture above):

```
crom.bezkoder.spring.datajpa
  -controller
  -model
  -repository
```

Is there a reason why Eclipse won't do what I ask it to do and create the package on the same level? It makes absolutely no sense that they're doing something else than what I ask it to do.

I am trying to follow the tutorial, but I think because of the package issues I am getting:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Apr 17 17:07:45 EDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-crud-rest-api/

Comment: Those are just two ways of showing the same thing. You can choose either in Project/Package Explorer using 'Package Presentation > Flat/Hierarchical'

Comment: Sorry, but where is the option?

Comment: It is in the 'view menu' - 3 vertical dots at the top right of the view (or a small triangle on older versions of Eclipse).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.